# Add pages links to javascript datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add pages links to different dates in jquery datepicker. With Click I want to go to specific date. Eg. If I click 1 it goes to page1.html, If I click 2 it go to page2.html.
Is it possible. If yes, then how?
Please help me

Comment: [jQuery datepicker onSelect](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) Add an event handler for the onSelect, evaluate what the date is, and do whatever you want.

Comment: Can you explain more please? with an example. I'm new learner to jquery